# How to hide checkbox from listview

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I need to hide checkboxes only from specified rows. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement an owner-drawn ListBox.  I have one which displays icons and checkboxes for all items, but you could easily modify it to only show the checkbox on specific items.

```
public class IconizedCheckedListBox : ListBox
{
    public IconizedCheckedListBox()
        : base()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;


        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            g.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);

        //e.DrawBackground();
        //e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        if (e.Index < Items.Count && e.Index != -1)
        {
            IconizedCheckedListBoxItem item = (IconizedCheckedListBoxItem)Items[e.Index];

            Rectangle checkBounds = e.Bounds;
            checkBounds.X += kCheckboxPadding;
            checkBounds.Y += (checkBounds.Height - kCheckboxSize) / 2;
            checkBounds.Width = kCheckboxSize;
            checkBounds.Height = kCheckboxSize;
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(g, checkBounds.Location, 
                item.Checked?CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal:CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                Rectangle textBounds = e.Bounds;
                textBounds.X += item.Icon.Width + 2*kCheckboxPadding + kCheckboxSize;
                textBounds.Y += 1;
                textBounds.Width -= item.Icon.Width;
                textBounds.Height -= 1;
                Font f;
                if (item.Checked)
                    f = new Font(Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                else
                    f = Font;
                g.DrawString(item.Data.ToString(), f, b, textBounds, format);
            }

            Image icon;
            if (!item.Checked)
                icon = Utilities.Utilities.WashOutImage(item.Icon);
            else
                icon = item.Icon;
            g.DrawImage(icon, e.Bounds.X + 2 * kCheckboxPadding + kCheckboxSize, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ItemHeight = kItemHeight;
    }

    protected override void  OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int idx = IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (idx != -1)
            {
                IconizedCheckedListBoxItem item = (IconizedCheckedListBoxItem)Items[idx];
                item.Checked = !item.Checked;

                if (ItemCheck != null)
                {
                    ItemCheckEventArgs args = new ItemCheckEventArgs(
                        idx,
                        item.Checked ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked,
                        CheckState.Indeterminate);
                    ItemCheck(this, args);
                }
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called AFTER the check state has been updated
    /// </summary>
    public event ItemCheckEventHandler ItemCheck;

    private const int kItemHeight = 32;
    private const int kCheckboxSize = 13;
    private const int kCheckboxPadding = 4;
}

public class IconizedCheckedListBoxItem
{
    public IconizedCheckedListBoxItem(Image inIcon, object inData)
    {
        Icon = inIcon;
        Data = inData;
        Checked = false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }

    public Image Icon;
    public object Data;
    public bool Checked;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for a "ListView" not "ListBox".  This is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are those rows headers?  If so, consider using [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx) in your ListView.

EDIT:

I'm not aware of any way to only show checkboxes on a subset of listview items.  An alternative for you would be to set the ForeColor of the items you want to gray, and in the ItemCheck event, reset the checkstate of these items to unchecked if they are checked.

Comment: No rows are not headers thay are just rows that should not be selected. Customer wanted to checkbox to be hidden